# read a binary file until the end

Tags: java, file

I have a series of different object serialized into a binary file.How can I read the file until the end?

```
    try {
        ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fname));

        Object obj = reader.readObject(); 

        if (obj instanceof Azienda) {
            Azienda a = (Azienda) obj;
            company.put(a.getCod(), a);
        } else if (obj instanceof Privato) {
            Privato p = (Privato) obj;
            privato.put(p.getCod(), p);
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ffe) {
        System.err.println("Error: the file was not found!");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

in this way I read only once object per read.

when I read a text file I use `null`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
try{
    while(true) {
       Object obj=reader.readObject()
     // do sth with object
    }
}catch(EOFException e){
//we expect it so ignore
}
```

there is no EOF check besides the exception when you read past it for ObjectInputStream so you'll have to use the code smell called exceptions for control flow

Comment: until an EOFException is thrown, signalling the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
    ObjectInputStream reader = null;

    try {
        reader = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("sth"));

        Object obj = null;
        while ((obj = reader.readObject()) != null) {
            System.out.println(obj);
        }


    } catch (EOFException e) {
        System.out.println("finnished reading");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println("Error: the file was not found!");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
```

Comment: -1. I thought this was the answer and tested it, but it doesn't return null at the end of the stream: it throws an EOFException.

Comment: sorry, you're right, but what is the problem then? just catch EOFException and don't forget to close file in finally, or am I wrong? // btw thanks @JbNizet I didn't try actually try it +1

Comment: There is no real problem, except it's not clearly documented (which means that the behavior could change in the future, although I doubt it). The other problem with your edited solution is that it's still implemented as if null was returned when the end of the stream is reached. The solution of ratchet freak is clearer, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that an EOFException is thrown when there is no more object to read from the stream. Unfortunately, it's not even documented. So, I see the following solutions:

- you read in a loop until you get this exception,
- you make it so that you know in advance the number of objects in the stream,
- you make it so that there is a marker object which marks the last object of the stream,
- you serialize (and unserialize) a unique object: a `List<Object>` containing all the objects. This last solution, of course prevents writing the objects on the fly to the stream, and forces you to have all the objects in memory before serializing them.

Answer (score 1):

`ObjectInputStream` does not have a concrete method for checking for end-of-file.

But every `read...()` method of `ObjectInputStream` throws an `EOFException` when it tries to read past the end of file. Unfortunately this is not explicitly documented for `readObject()`, but it is for all the other methods (`readInt()` etc.)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html

Comment: +1 for noticing that the EOFException is documented for other readXxx methods. It's a pity it isn't for readObject, which is the most used method of an ObjectInputStream.